# Custom JsonConverter skip internal object

Tags: c#, json.net

I need to transform a class in a JSON but I want only base property.

For example in the following class A i need only the first 3 property but i cannot modify the class (is autogenerated from the database).
I alreayd created a custom JsonConverter and populated the method CanConvert with my logic, but this didn't works and convert a list of object A result in OutOfMemory Exception

```
class A {
   string name {get; set;}
   string surname {get; set;}
   string roleCode {get; set;}
   Role role {get; set;}
}

-----

public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
{
    var isDate = objectType == typeof(DateTime) || objectType == typeof(DateTime?) || objectType == typeof(Nullable<DateTime>);
    var isString = objectType == typeof(string);
    var isClass = objectType.IsClass;
    return !isClass && !(isDate || isString);
}
```

Comment: No need to write your own converter, if you don't need certain properties in your resulting json you can ignore them with a `JsonIgnoreAttribute`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/ignore-properties?pivots=dotnet-7-0

Comment: @RolandDeschain - OP specifically wrote that they *cannot modify the class* so they cannot apply `[JsonIgnore]`.  Also that doc link is for System.Text.Json but OP seems to be using Json.NET.

Comment: Oh, my bad, completely missed that. Nevermind then...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a custom ContractResolver:
[See Json.NET Documentation](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ConditionalProperties.htm)
For your case it could look like this:

```
public class ShouldSerializeContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        JsonProperty property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);

        if (property.DeclaringType == typeof(A) && property.PropertyName == "role")
        {
            property.ShouldSerialize = instance => false;
        }

        return property;
    }
}
```

And use it (loTestObject is instance from type `A`):

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(loTestObject,
    Formatting.Indented,
    new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new ShouldSerializeContractResolver() }
);
```